# Why doesn't Nullable<T> implement IComparable?

Tags: .net, generics

The answer to this is probably glaringly obvious, but I'll stoop to asking anyway.

I was in the midst of writing a `Range<T>` class, and in the process realized I needed a comparer for it. So, I wrote a generic comparer, derived, naturally, from `Comparer<T>`:

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable
{

    // Simplified here for brevity -- actually uses the comparer
    public T Min { get; set; }

    // Simplified here for brevity -- actually uses the comparer
    public T Max { get; set; }

    private class DefaultComparer : Comparer<T> 
    {
        public override int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return x == null && y == null 
                ? 0 
                : x == null 
                    ? -1 
                    : y == null 
                        ? 1 
                        : x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this all works fine and well, until you pass a `Nullable<T>` as the type. For example:

```
public Range<DateTime?> DateSentFilter { get; set; }
```

This breaks horribly, because, of course, `Nullable<T>` doesn't implement `IComparable`. And this got me to thinking: Why not?

Given how a comparer is generally written, why couldn't it?

Does anyone with deep knowledge of this stuff have any idea? Is there a scenario that would prohibit this from being done?

Comment: What if `T` doesn't implement `IComparable<T>`? Or more generally, what if I wanted a `Nullable<T>` that did _not_ implement `IComparable`?

Comment: Yeah, you're essentially asking why don't' **ALL** the types implement `IComparable`?

Comment: a.k.a. "what if I don't _feel_ like it?"

Comment: @Chris, I suppose there's some merit to that, but it seems to me that `Nullable<T>` was created to deal with the built-in types and structs, all of which are `IComparable`. So, excluding classes, it *seems* like an oversight to omit the implementation of IComparable on `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @MikeHofer `Nullable<T>` is useful for all structs, not just in-built ones. And new structs aren't necessarily `IComparable`. It'd be bizarre if I had to implement `IComparable` for a struct just so that I could have a nullable version

Comment: Why the ugly formatting and using of ternary operators when you can just use plain nested `if()` statements? Are you trying to make your code extra hard to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a comment from the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,c9505a785f9fd8c5):

```
// Warning, don't put System.Runtime.Serialization.On*Serializ*Attribute
// on this class without first fixing ObjectClone::InvokeVtsCallbacks
// Also, because we have special type system support that says a a boxed Nullable<T>
// can be used where a boxed<T> is use, Nullable<T> can not implement any intefaces
// at all (since T may not).   Do NOT add any interfaces to Nullable!
//
```

As it says, `Nullable<T>` can't implement any interfaces for given reasons.

Now, the second question is: **if it could, would they implement `IComparable`?** No. Patrick has told why. Not every `T` implements `IComparable`, it just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Now that's an answer I could get behind! A reason! And it poses an interesting question. If they could, would they? I'd like to hope so.

Comment: No, they could *not* for the reasons outlined by Patrick and John.

Comment: @MikeHofer: Not sure if you know this, but every type has default comparer. You can remove the generic restriction, and just use `Comparer<DateTime?>.Default` - the default comparer is not stupid: it'll take advantange of the fact that `DateTime` implements `IComparable` and that we're dealing with nullable `DateTime`.(wraps it into `NullableComparer`).

Comment: They don't check grammar in their comments much, do they?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the generic type provided to `Nullable<T>` doesn't need to implement `IComparable` itself.

You have provided this condition yourself: `T : IComparable`, but that is not necessarily true for the `T` in `Nullable<T>`. I will agree that `Nullable<T>` is often used on primitive types that do implement `IComparable` but you could use it on structs, and they don't have `IComparable` implemented.